# quadratic equation with multiple fractions

Tags: quadratics, fractions

I'm trying to solve a quadratic equation with multiple fractions, I haven't been able to find anything similar to this online. I need this broken down step by step especially when eliminating the fractions. Bonus points if you can point to a direct resource with practice problems or tutorials with similar problems as I need to solve numerous equations like this one.

$$\frac{3}{x-1} - \frac{x}{2x-2} = -1$$

Can you help me?

Comment: have you attempted any work on this question yourself? Show us what you've tried so we can help you better.

Comment: Welcome to the community.  You need to work on your formatting.  If you have more than 1 term in the denominator of a fraction, then put it in parentheses.  Or even better, use math jax  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Try multiplying through by whatever you need to to eliminate the fractions.

Comment: My 1st thought was of course to multiply both sides by each denominator but I'm not coming up with anything that looks right before I even get to apply the quadratic method

Comment: if x = -4 it  works but I haven't found an effective way to solve the problem other than guessing numbers to plug in

Comment: Well, at least I'm not the only person that can't solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson, 
Both of those denominators are going to be your LCD. The way I like to do these is very long hand--but it works and I haven't really found a simpler way to do it. You're going to multiply each term by the LCD on both sides of the equation.

(x-1)(2x-2) is going to be the LCD

Again, this is really, really long hand.

(x-1)(2x-2)/1 * 3/x-1 - x/2x-2 * (x-1)(2x-2)/1 = -1 * (x-1)(2x-2)/1

After putting the LCD in fraction form, the matching parts in the numerators and denominators will cancel out, you will then multiply the remaining parts of the denominator and solve as needed. I hope this helps.

Comment: so using the quadratic method I get -4 or 1, but since using x=1 in this problem makes the denominators == 0 you cannot use x=1 so you're left with just x= -4 . I'm assuming division by 0 is not allowed

Comment: Correct, (x+4) and (x-1)